# Why doesn't a dataset created in matlab's simulink offer me get.Element function?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm doing a tutorial to learn matlab and simulink, and it came to a part where you run the .slx model from the script and extract data from it. The issue is that my matlab doesn't offer the same options for a dataset compared to the tutorial, specifically the get.Element option

picture to make it clearer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epFx9.jpg)

Comment: Which version of MATLAB was the tutorial written for and which version are you running? The Simulink.SimulationData.Dataset was introduced back in R2011a. Perhaps you can also share what error you are getting. Not clear from your attached image.

Comment: The current documentation only has `get` and not a `getElement` method.